# OpenGL Face Order

Tags: opengl, shaders, 3d-meshes

i have written a simple OBJ-file loader to render meshes using OpenGL.
But there is a problem displaying the loaded mesh. It seems that faces that from the background (far) are displayed above the front faces.

To illustrate the problem i have rendered a little example picture (Blender monkey).

[image: Blender monkey mesh face order problem]

I am using really simple shaders:

**Vertex shader**

```
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec3 vert;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 uv;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

out vec2 frag_uv;
out vec3 frag_vert;

void main()
{
    gl_Position  = vec4(vert, 1);
    gl_Position *= model;
    gl_Position *= view;
    gl_Position *= projection;

    frag_vert = vec3(vec4(vert, 1) * model);
    frag_uv = uv;
}
```

**Fragment shader**

```
#version 330

in vec2 frag_uv;
in vec3 frag_vert;

out vec4 color;

void main()
{
    color = vec4(frag_vert.x, frag_vert.y, frag_vert.z, 1.0);
}
```

The mesh is rendered using a VBO and a VAO.
I have no clue ehat i am doing wrong.
Thank you, and a nice christmas :)

Comment: How did you set up your depth buffer?

Comment: I did not set up a depth buffer

Comment: Is Your near plane set to 0?

Comment: I forgot to enable depth testing.
This is solved. Thank you.

    `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)`

was missing.

Comment: @Johannes If you have solved your problem please consider answering your own question instead of just commenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**

Depth testing was not enabled:

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

... fixed the Problem.